# Accessing event trigger button onclick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-graph-vis

I have using to react-graph-vis package like below

```
    <Graph
      ref={graph}
      graph={data}
      options={options()}
      events={events}
    />
```

event prop triggers when i press the graph element and events func like below

```
  const events = {
    select: function(event) {
      var { nodes, edges } = event;
    }
  };
```

I want to access the event from another button onClick, how can I do that, thanks for suggestion

Comment: Is ``events`` a local variable or a global variable?

Comment: events is local variable

Comment: You can accept my answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `events` a global variable. Set it in the state as `myEvent` or whatever you'd like to name it and do this:

```js
this.setState({myEvent: events}) // replace myEvent as whatever you'd like to call it
```

You can reference it by
`this.state.myEvent`. To call `select` do `this.state.myEvent.select(e)` assuming `e` is the `event` parameter.